# Bookmarklet: Append hidden iframe to page and load url

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bookmarklet, router

I have a bookmarklet for resetting my router. I just need to visit and let the page finish loading, then my router starts resetting.

```
javascript:(function(){w=window.open("http://192.168.0.1/goform/formReboot","","width=1,height=1");self.focus();window.onload=w.close();})();
```

But it opens in a popup window.

My new idea is to dynamically append an hidden iframe to the page I'm on using a javascript bookmaklet, and then open the url in the hidden iframe. Is this even possible?

I'm open for better suggestion on how this can be done.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An even easier way would be to create a new IMG element:

```
(function(){
    (new Image()).src = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/formReboot";
})();
```

As a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void((function(){(new Image()).src = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/formReboot";})());
```

---

Or, if that doesn't work, here's the 'iframe' creator you requested:

```
(function(){
    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
    i.style.display = 'none';
    i.onload = function() { i.parentNode.removeChild(i); };
    i.src = 'http://192.168.0.1/goform/formReboot';
    document.body.appendChild(i);
})();
```

Comment: Why are you using void() around the code, when you're already using (function(){}) ?

Answer (score 3):

Can it be done? Sure!

1. Create an iframe element, with
   whatever parameters needed
2. Add it
   as the last child to the body
   element
3. Done!

Here's an example (everything would go on one line):

```
javascript:var%20ifra=document.createElement('iframe');
ifra.src="http://www.chron.com";
ifra.setAttribute("height","230");
ifra.setAttribute("width","360");
void(document.body.appendChild(ifra));
```