# Run protocol handler without opening windows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a javascript that opens FILE with TextMate with txmt protocol.
It works fine, but the problem is that I have a blank Safari window when this script is run.

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 69 && isCtrl == true) {
        mywindow = window.open("txmt://open/?url=file://FILE","myWindow");
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I not open the blank window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `window.location = "your link"`

Comment: Littlebit tricky solution. When the protocol is unknown, an empty window will be opened and you leaving the current page. If javascript is enabled, create a hidden iframe that opens that url.

Comment: @Erwinus - Agreed, plus changing location may break certain things (long-polling is one example I came across). A good example of how to implement the iFrame solution can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/635750/3412775

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).  Might work.

Answer (score 0):

"Make your link, then simulate a click on it." was my first thought on how to do this. I've now tried it and it doesn't work, so I edited the answer to reply with this comment. It works fine for http links but not for anything else. I'm leaving this here because I would be interested if anyone knows why it doesn't work.