# How do I position an iframe via javascript code as a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

i know how to position iframes via html, but I'm making a bookmarklet, which of course, is javascript.

I've extrapolated the lessons from this question's 2nd answer: [Bookmarklet: Append hidden iframe to page and load url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635622/bookmarklet-append-hidden-iframe-to-page-and-load-url)

and come up with this:

`javascript:var%20ifra=document.createElement('iframe');ifra.src="https://imanerd11.kd.io/temp1.html";ifra.setAttribute("width","194");ifra.setAttribute("height","750");ifra.setAttribute("left","0");ifra.setAttribute("borders","no");ifra.setAttribute("scrollbars","no");ifra.setAttribute("top","0");void(document.body.appendChild(ifra));`

[image]

- that's the screenshot of what it does currently.

I need to be able to move this to the side of the page like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` and `left` aren't attributes, they are CSS properties.

You can set the styles programmatically like:

```
ifra.style.top = '100px';
```

You can also use the style attribute:

```
ifra.setAttribute('style', 'top: 10px; left: 10px;');
```

**Note: Do not forget that these will be ignored if the element isin't positionned *absolute* or *relative*.**